# JavaScript continuously check a variable

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck at watching a boolean variable. On my program I am setting the value of mutexSelect "true". Whenever the value is true, makeIntoSelect function must be called like below;

```
 (here I want to declare to watch muteSelect value continuously){
     if (mutexSelect == true) {
         mutexSelect = false;
         makeIntoSelect(newSelectedItem);
     }
 });
```

How can I check the value of mutexSelect continuously?
Thanks!

Comment: Well the best solution is to trigger a message when you alter the variable and not have to keep checking it.

Comment: you should use [websockets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm)

Comment: What about combine `setInterval` and `ajax`

Comment: @Mr.x Why that?!

Comment: Both answers used `setInterval`, then you ask me why? @A.Wolff

Comment: @Mr.x imho, both answers are bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this solution is like using duct tape to fix something that really needs a replacement piece. The best solution would be to trigger a message when the variable is updated. Not seeing how the varaible gets updated, I can not give you a good solution here. But [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) can show you how to trigger a custom event.

So what is your only other choice? Using an interval and checking to see if it has been flipped.

```
window.setInterval( function(){
  if (mutexSelect == true) {
     mutexSelect = false;
     makeIntoSelect(newSelectedItem);
  }
},10)
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I could use! But I am going to look at MDN Docs. Maybe I could find a better trigger than an interval. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery setInterval function. This function will trigger continuously at given interval so that you can place your code inside that function.

[jQuery SetInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    if (mutexSelect == true) {
        mutexSelect = false;
        makeIntoSelect(newSelectedItem);
    }  
}, 1000);
```

Update the call back time as you wish to get this function to trigger more frequently. (i.e) Change the value from 1000 to your desired value.

Comment: setInterval is **NOT** a jQuery function or anything.